# Clustering/High availability on SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.3

I would like to know whether SonarQube will support HA/clustering? How to overcome the fail over situation of SonarQube instance when there is a hardware failure.?

For example, I have two SonarQube instances are running on two different machines. Also I have a separate machine for storage/DB used by two Sonar instances. How to proceed to achieve HA for this situation.?

Answer (score 2):

HA is not supported right now. Clustering is planned for end of this year.

Comment: I too would also like to see some form of HA / Clustering please - thanks

Comment: Thanks Simon. Whether SonarQube supports Hardware Load balancing.?

Comment: To achieve fail over/HA what is the best architecture.?

Comment: As I said it's not supported yet.